# Concurrent Read & Write in Lucene

Tags: java, concurrency, lucene

I have an application that needs to be able to read and write a search index concurrently. What I noticed with lucene is that you can't use IndexWriter and DirectoryReader concurrently. Basically:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
//Add documents here...
writer.commit();

DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer.getDirectory());
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);     
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46,"field", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46));
qp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query q = qp.parse("field:*");
```

works fine, while

```
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46));
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
writer.commit();
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer.getDirectory());

//Add documents here

writer.commit();
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);     
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46,"field", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46));
qp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query q = qp.parse("field:*");
```

doesn't work at all.

Do I have to reopen the DirectoryReader after each commit?

Comment: Yes, you must reopen. An alternative is the Near-Realtime Reader. Check out this blog entry: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html

Answer (score 1):

As we could see the main difference between two snippies is the time u got a reader from the `IndexWriter`, first one is after the `writer.commit()` .

---

when we got a reader ,that means we've got a one-time-snapshot of the current Index file, the second `reader` got a "snapshot" before the  `IndexWriter.commit` , it will turn out that the `IndexSearcher`  based on that `reader` won't find changes `IndexWriter` just made or the Index isn't in a consistent state .

so u should reopen the DirectoryReader . hope these will do some help ！ :D